# Is there a “FORCMD” variable (like “DIRCMD”, “COPYCMD”, etc.)?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, ms-dos, default-settings

The `dir` command checks for a `dircmd` environment variable for default arugments to use. Likewise, the `copy` and `move` commands check `copycmd`. Is there a corresponding variable (by any name) for the `for` command or another way to specify default arguments for the `for` command?

Whenever I use the `for` command to parse a file (using the `/f` switch), I *always* (so far) use the `"delims="` argument. This is annoying to type (especially when I forget it).

Is there a way to set default arguments for the `for` command? (I tested using a `forcmd` variable, but it did not work. If so, does it work in DOS as well as the Windows command-prompt?

Comment: Argh! I’m using `for`’s `/f` switch a lot more these days to accommodate its [inability to see hidden objects](http://superuser.com/questions/475881/for-command-cannot-see-hidden-files). I almost always have to specify the `delims=` option to allow it to work with filenames with spaces, so it is aggravating that there is no way to have it always be specified.`◔_◔`

Answer (score 1):

No.

The Windows command prompt's `for` built-in doesn't support anything called "FORCMD".  No environment variable will change its behavior.  There is no way to specify its defaults.

`cmd.exe` is an enhancement of the true DOS's `command.com` - it supported "Command Extensions" which extended and modified the behavior of many commands, including all the extra stuff on `for`.

`cmd.exe` is a Win32 executable and will not work under true 16-bit native DOS.  `command.com`, which will, does not support the `cmd.exe` extensions - and the same applies as the `cmd.exe`'s for: no environment variable changes its behavior and there is no way to specify its defaults (not that it would be useful as the `command.com` `for` is much more limited)

Still available via 32-bit versions of Windows, at least up to XP, is the old macro utility `doskey` that was included starting at MS-DOS version 5 or 6 and kept at least til XP.  Defining some macros may help you avoid a bit of extra typing.

Comment: I am familiar with *everything* you said. *None* of that was an answer to the question I asked.

Comment: Sorry.  To put it more clearly, the answer is "No."  I have edited the answer to include this.

Comment: *> No. The Windows command prompt's for built-in doesn't support anything called "FORCMD".* Obviously there is not a `forcmd` variable, I already tested that. That’s why I asked if there was one by another name.

Comment: Where?​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Check the edits to see.  Also add some of your own if you have further ideas for clarification.

Comment: The sole [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/391806/revisions) is the addition of `No.`

Comment: I then invite anyone else to edit my comment to be more clear.  Though I fully believe simplifying "No" any further will be a challenge, but I'll stay posted.

Comment: I’m confused; you said you added “No.”, then you said you added “further clarification”, but there is no further edits. Your second edit seems not to have taken.

Comment: Having weirdness on my end too.  Possibly forgot to click Submit.

Comment: Hmm, that’s pretty queer because `dir` and `copy/move` check for envvars even in DOS. I find it surprising (and frustrating) that they never figured people may need to set defaults for the `for` command (especially once it got so complex in Windows). `:-|`