# FOR command cannot see hidden files

Tags: windows, command-line

I’m struggling with one of the most frustrating bugs I’ve ever come across.

**Bug description:**

The `for` command of the command-interpreter cannot see hidden files.

**Reproduction steps:**

1. Create a temporary directory
2. Create a few files
3. Assign a variety of attributes to the files (including hidden)
4. Use a command like `for %i in (*) do echo "%i"`

**Expected results:**

All files are processed in the `for` loop either by default or though a switch.

**Actual results:**

- Files with any attribute other than hidden are processed; files flagged as hidden are skipped
- There is no switch to the `for` command to allow it to process hidden files

**Implications:**

There is no way to process *all* files from the command-prompt.

**Question:**

How the heck can hidden files be processed from the command-prompt or batch-files (at least in Windows if not DOS)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one (ugly, unpleasant, non-ideal) work-around for files:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %i in ('dir /b/a-d *') do echo "%i"
```

And a version for folders (analogous to `for /d…`):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %i in ('dir /b/ad  *') do echo "%i"
```

And a version for both (no `for` analog, so this is something of a benefit):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %i in ('dir /b/a   *') do echo "%i"
```

Recursive version for files (`for… /r`):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %i in ('dir /b/s/a-d *') do echo "%i"
```

And folders (`for /r /d…`):

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %i in ('dir /b/s/ad  *') do echo "%i"
```

And both

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %i in ('dir /b/s/a   *') do echo "%i"
```

This works more or less, but definitely has its issues (especially for large sets of files or folders). Hopefully there is a better solution or Microsoft could fix/improve this in a patch.

Comment: With `tokens=*` you can omit the `delims=` option, and the `*` is redundant. Also `dir /b/a` will list directories as well as files. If you want files only, you need `dir /b/a:-d`. And since this behavior of the Windows command line hasn't changed in, like, 20 years, it's probably not going to change now. Don't like it? Use VBScript or PowerShell instead.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, thanks for the tips. I don’t usually use `/f` other than to process the lines in a text file (e.g., `for /f "delims=" %i in (list.txt)…`), so I don’t know the extra options that well. You’re right about `/a` listing directories; I don’t know why my earlier test did not list them.

Comment: @Synetech, hmm, I improved the answer and an up-vote got rescinded. I guess that’ll learn me to make things better from now on. *sigh*

Comment: I just had to resort to this for a new batch-file I wrote and to be honest, it wasn’t that bad. It performs well *enough* and was simple to remember and use (I left the `tokens` and `delims` options out altogether for this one). I’m going to accept this for now because it retains the `for` syntax, so nothing has to be rewritten, and it “just works”.

Comment: I’ve been using the `/f` switch to use a command for the loop expression a lot over the past months and to be honest, I am really getting used to it. It still has the drawback that it must first enumerate all files/folders to build a list before even starting the command, but it also has some benefits like **•** using `dir` to access hidden/system files/folders and **•** building the list before processing avoids re-processing items that are modified; a regular `for` loop enumerates in situ, so it can enter an infinite loop since modified objects can appear as *new* ones to be (re-)processed.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`forfiles`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551(v=ws.10).aspx) instead of `for`.

The syntax is quite different, but it has more functionalities (e.g., method to natively access the filename, the extension, the filesize and timestamp) and it processes *all* files by default.

For example, instead of

```
for %i in (*) do echo "%i"
```

you'd use

```
forfiles /c "cmd /c echo @file"
```

or simply

```
forfiles
```

since `"cmd /c echo @file"` is the default value for the command switch.

Comment: Not bad. It uses a different syntax and isn’t available in XP, but it’s good to have an option. (I actually considered a Unix port, but while `ls.exe` is useful, the `for` command is built into the shell like it is in Windows. I suppose one could use a Unix shell port, but then that wouldn’t be the Windows command-prompt.)

Comment: You could pipe the output of `ls` to `xargs` or simply use `find`. Both are available for Windows.

Comment: Hmm, interesting suggestion. The problem is that running external commands like that would severely impact the performance, especially when there’s lots of files/folders (at least as compared to the built-in `for` command).