# How do I search for non-hidden files in hidden subfolders using Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, search, dir

Looking through Google and super user stack exchange showed me how to search a folder and it's subfolder for hidden files

`dir /A:H /S testHiddenFile*.txt`

or hidden folders:

`dir /A:HD /S testFolder`

But how do I search through all sub folders (hidden or non-hidden) for all files with a particular extension. For example I want to find the location of `*.log` files under `C:\Users\SomeUser\` but these files could be under hidden folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `attrib /s /d *.*` command. See more: https://ss64.com/nt/attrib.html

Answer (score 3):

Taken and adapted from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/475881/for-command-cannot-see-hidden-files), it will recurse through all folders whether or not they are Hidden and find files whether or they are hidden:

```
REM Recursive scan through all folders with or without Hidden attribute for any files
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %i in ('dir /b/s/a-d *') do echo "%i"
```

Adapted for your taste for finding all `*.log` files:

```
REM Recursive scan through all folders with or without Hidden attribute for .log files
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %i in ('dir /b/s/a-d *.log') do echo "%i"
```

If you want to save their directories to file `myFiles.txt`:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %i in ('dir /b/s/a-d *.log') do echo "%i">>myFiles.txt
```

If you want to open all your files one at time:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir /b/s/a-d *.log') do (
    pause
    echo.
    echo Opening file "%%i"...
    notepad.exe "%%i"
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted cause this worked as well, though it's longer than the answer in @Biswa's comment (`attrib /s/d *.log`).